# How to add autotools based project to qmake project?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qmake, autotools

Have a nice day.
I develop cross-platform app using Qt. 
My app depends on C library. The library doesn't depend on other libraries and it uses autotools as build system.

I can build it in command line and replace *.a file to some folder, add linker flags and includes, but I don't want do it manually for every platform.

I want use it like the QtCreator Kits. So if I select Android kit I expect that qmake reconfigure, rebuild and links target library.

Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried to create qmake project file for library?

Comment: Of course I did it. I use subdirs template for a main project and lib template for the library but I don't know what I should to write in ExternalLib.pro file to invoke configure script with appropriate enviroment variables.

Comment: If you have defined HEADERS, SOURCES and other qmake stuff in project file for external lib, then your library will get build by qmake with other your sources. Also qmake even can import sources to dummy qmake project.

Comment: Headers and sources files were added, but they can't be compiled because "configure" step was skipped. And if I make ./configure I don't shure that it would be correct for all platforms.

Comment: Nope in this case you dont need the configure step. All you need is library template with defines, compiler/linker flags, rules for autogenerated headers if any. You should provide more details like library, error messages.